# What is the appropriate verb and preposition to say "play the lottery"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Do we play the lottery? Do we play in/on the lottery? Do we bet the lottery?

What is the appropriate verb for the sentence and is it necessary to use a preposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we say is "play the lottery." It's ungrammatical if you put in a preposition.

I don't ever say "bet" when talking about a specific game. I might "play craps" or "play roulette" but I would never say that I "?bet on/in the lottery/craps/roulette" and it would sound a little strange to me if I heard anyone else say that.

I would only use bet to describe a specific wager. E.g. "I bet on number 32."